# a img {border:0;} not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following code and I still see the border under an image. Any idea?

```
a, a:visited {
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
    border: 0;
}
```

Maybe I should add that I'm working locally...

Code Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8WzMJ/

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105720/cannot-get-rid-of-a-bizarre-2px-space-between-my-child-image-and-parent-div ?

Comment: not really, I don't see an empty space but an actual border

Comment: Please create a code example on http://jsfiddle.net so we can see what is not working

Comment: What makes you think it is an actual border? Does it change color if you use `border-bottom: 2px solid red`? Where is your HTML code? Does it reproduce the problem with the CSS included in the question and nothing more?

Comment: I added a code example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put an image inside anchor and give border bottom to anchor, to remove that, remove border from the anchor

```
a,
a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

or add class to anchor and style it without border

```
<a class="without-border" href="http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg">
  <img src="http://www.seobook.com/images/smallfish.jpg" />
</a>

.without-border {
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: Well, actually the code is supposed to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49966/how-to-remove-black-border-around-hyperlinked-image

Comment: Well, how to explain this...you don't have a border around image, you have `border-bottom: 2px solid black;` assigned to anchor which holds image inside it and to remove that black border below the image you must remove it from the default anchor style or add class to anchor you use with image inside it and style it without border.

Comment: Thanks, I find it absurd there is no a "clean" way to achieve this. In  any case I'm doing it via jQuery with `$('a:has(img)').addClass('without-border');`as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794677/css-target-text-links-with-bottom-border-on-hover-but-image-links-with-no-bord

Comment: You're welcome, of course you can assign class via jQuery it's simpler for later html coding.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I don't know what the impact of this might be, but you could try:

```
img{
    float:left;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
```